# Change NamespaceManager on Full Text Search GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

We have an application in GAE, and we are reenginering this to use Full Text. We have to index all data already in the GAE and our application also use namespaces.

We are trying to create a java procedure to be runned by administrator, who has not namespace. In other services, we have created similar java procedures, applying namespace by code, so the idea is to index all data in each namespace. (We use NamespaceFilter to control user domain.)

This is part of code:

```java
private static final Index INDEX = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService()
  .getIndex(IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName("Actividad"));

NamespaceManager.set("userdomain1");
INDEX.add(doc);
```

Setting namespace is ignored.

Is this the expected behaviour? Is there an alternative way to index all the information in every namespace?

With similar code on datastore it's work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SearchService object is bound to a namespace, so you need to call NamespaceManager.set() before calling SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService().  Alternatively, call the version of getSearchService() that has a namespace parameter. See:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/search/SearchServiceFactory#getSearchService(java.lang.String)